# How to customize range slider tick in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi I am trying to customize the v-slider tick in vuetify 1.5 to acheive something like this i.e custom scale icon.

[image]

I have tried modifying v-slider__ticks and making it look like the scale by modifiying border radius property. But facing a issue where it just appears under the slider instead of appearing at the center. This is what I have tried till now. Any suggestions to fix it would be helpful.
[image]

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/akshayd21/pen/KKWxeWx

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
          value: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-slider__ticks{
  border-left: 0.5px solid !important;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex>
           <v-card flat color="transparent">
      <v-subheader>Custom Range Tick</v-subheader>
  
      <v-card-text>
        <v-slider
          v-model="value"
          step="10"
          ticks="always"
          tick-labels="abcdefghijkl"
        ></v-slider>
      </v-card-text>
  
    </v-card>
  
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an negative `top` value

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
          value: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-slider__ticks{
  border-left: 0.5px solid !important;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  top: -5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex>
           <v-card flat color="transparent">
      <v-subheader>Custom Range Tick</v-subheader>
  
      <v-card-text>
        <v-slider
          v-model="value"
          step="10"
          ticks="always"
          tick-labels="abcdefghijkl"
        ></v-slider>
      </v-card-text>
  
    </v-card>
  
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```